# Function that takes file pointer and 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to write a simple program that creates a 2D array and then prints it out.
I want to write a function that reads from an input file and creates the array.
Then, in the main function, I want to call the function to make the array and then print it out.
I know this is basic stuff but I can't find this answer anywhere in my textbook or online.
The input file is just a text file written exactly like the array' 12 row with 8 random numbers in each row.

```
#include <stdio.h>



void makeArray(FILE*ptr, int array[12][8]){
    int i,j;
    ptr = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    for (i=0; i<12; i++){
        for (j=0; j<8; j++){
            fscanf(ptr, "%d", array[i][j]);
            }
    }   

}


int main(){
    int i, j;
    int scores[12][8];
    FILE*input;
    void makeArray(input, scores);
    for (i=0; i<12; i++){
        for (j=0; j<8; j++){
            printf("%d\t", scores[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` requires a pointer: `fscanf(ptr, "%d", &array[i][j]);`

Comment: Thanks, but did didn't help at all. The numbers that show up in the output aren't even numbers I typed.

Comment: Why did you pass a pointer to a FILE if you use it only once?

Comment: `void makeArray(input, scores);`. That declares a function prototype and does not call the function as you intend. Get rid of the `void`. Note that the compiler should have warned you about that (and also about the `fscanf` error pointed out by @JohnnyMopp) and you probably ignored it - always heed the compiler warnings.

Comment: I love you. I love you. I looooove you. (That's from Elf)

Comment: In C89 `void makeArray(input, scores);` isn't an error, so the compiler probably shouldn't warn.  Using the compiler's C99 or C11 would be a good idea.

Comment: @M.M Not a warning for the prototype per se (sorry, I didn't make that clear). But that the parameters have no types. `warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]`

Comment: @kaylum sorry, I thought it meant they were implicitly `int` but in fact it is a mistake as you say

Comment: Also, on a less critical note, it is good practice to close the file you opened by calling fclose function. You should do that at the end of your makeArray function, if you are curious as to when you should do that.